# Same-size flexboxes are broken with Highcharts

Tags: css, highcharts, flexbox

I'm trying to create two stacked charts of the same height by using flex items.

See the following code, for instance. The two chart containers `#chart1` and `#chart2` do have the same size when the charts are not yet created, but it's not the case any more after their creation (by clicking on the button).

Calling `chart.reflow()` after a while does not help. What can I do to solve this problem?

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  const options = {
    chart: {backgroundColor: 'transparent'},
    title: {text: 'Test'},
    series: [{data: [[0, 0], [1, 3]]}]
  };

  const chart1 = Highcharts.chart('chart1', options);
  const chart2 = Highcharts.chart('chart2', options);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#chart1 {
  background: lightcyan;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#chart2 {
  background: lightyellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/9.2.1/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <button id="button">Load charts</button>
  <div id="chart1">Same size</div>
  <div id="chart2">Same size</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8312), you should add `flex-basis: 0` and `overflow:hidden` to the chart containers. Note that if you have several levels of flexboxes one into each other, you should add this at every level.

```css
#chart1 {
  background: lightcyan;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#chart2 {
  background: lightyellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```